# Shuffle between SSE integer registers

Tags: c++, sse

I have two sse integers which i am assigning it as follows:

```
    __m128i m1 = _mm_set_epi32(4,3,2,1);
    __m128i m2 = _mm_set_epi32(40,30,20,10);
```

Now, I have to do some shuffle between these two registers and store the result in another two registers such that the output will be as follows:

```
     m3 = (30,3,10,1);
     m4 = (40,4,20,2);
```

Is there any way that i can achieve this!!

Thanks

Comment: But i want to do with sse shuffle

Comment: @MarcoA. That is used to shuffle within a single register... I want to shuffle between two registers

Comment: Right, sorry. I should have read more carefully

Comment: @MarcoA. No problem. But u have any idea?

Comment: To be honest yes, but unfortunately I'm way too tired to experiment with it, sorry :/ I might try it tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
t1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m1, 0xd8);
t2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m2, 0xd8);       
m4 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1,t2);
m3 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(t1,t2);
```

Here is a full example

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        __m128i m1 = _mm_set_epi32(4,3,2,1);
        __m128i m2 = _mm_set_epi32(40,30,20,10);

        __m128i m3, m4, t1, t2;
        t1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m1, 0xd8);
        t2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m2, 0xd8);       
        m4 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1,t2);
        m3 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(t1,t2);

        int out3[4], out4[4];
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)out3, m3);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)out4, m4);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", out3[3], out3[2], out3[1], out3[0]);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", out4[3], out4[2], out4[1], out4[0]);
}
```

Output

```
30 3 10 1
40 4 20 2
```

Comment: BTW 0xd8 = 3120 in base-4 (and 11011000 in binary). This tells you which numbers I'm swapping. I know base-4 is not typical to think in but it's convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a slightly different solution to Z Boson:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void print_data(const char *name, __m128i v)
{
    struct { int a, b, c, d; } unpacked;

    std::memcpy((void *)&unpacked, (void *)&v, sizeof(v));
    std::cout << name << ":";
    std::cout << unpacked.d << " " << unpacked.c << " " 
          << unpacked.b << " " << unpacked.a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    __m128i m1 = _mm_set_epi32(4,3,2,1);
    __m128i m2 = _mm_set_epi32(40,30,20,10);
    __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi32(-1,0,-1,0);

    /*
     m3 = (30,3,10,1);  
     m4 = (40,4,20,2);
    */

    __m128i tmp1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m2, 0x80);
    __m128i tmp2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(m1, 0x31);
    __m128i m3 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(mask, tmp1), _mm_andnot_si128(mask, m1));
    __m128i m4 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(mask, m2), _mm_andnot_si128(mask, tmp2));

    print_data("m3", m3);
    print_data("m4", m4);
}
```

I'm sure the unpack variant is slightly better...